# .NET Core, failed to spawn dotnet --info

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When I type `dotnet --info` in cmd the entire screen is covered in `Failed to leave breadcrumb`

What can cause such behavior? Searched on google but it seems like I'm the only person that has that problem. Recently, when I tried to work with Visual studio Code I installed a c# extension and opened my .cs file and I got this message

```
Updating C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)' (21928 KB) .................... Done!
Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)' (39217 KB) .................... Done!

Installing package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)'

Finished
Failed to spawn 'dotnet --info'
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this myself.

You may have missed the bit of info in the header that pointed you to this URL.
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

You need to install .net core.

Comment: Ive reinstalled it almost 5 times trying every possible setting

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install [.NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net471)

you also need [.NET SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows#windowscmd)

open cmd where dotnet.exe exist (like)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

run the followind in cmd

```
dotnet --info
```

Comment: The .NET Framework and .NET Core are two competing frameworks.  You don't need to install  .NET Framework if you want .NET Core.

Comment: The choco installer for vscode installs .NET Framework as well, though. Not sure why that is.